# php Retrieve from a xml file having equal values

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to recover only some values ​​from an xlsx file. The file that creates problems for me is worksheets / sheet1.xml whose structure is
...

```
<sheetData>
    <row (attribbutes)>
        <c (attributes)>
            <v>value</v>
        </c>    
        .....
        <c (attributes)>
            <v>value</v>
        </c>
    </row>
    ......      
    <row (attribbutes)>
        <c (attributes)>
            <v>value</v>
        </c>    
        .....
        <c (attributes)>
            <v>value</v>
        </c>
    </row>
</sheetData>
```

my problem is that the values ​​that interest me are in different lines but they can be the same. For example: I need the number of the day of the month (e.g. 16), but that number is also the pointer that allows me to find the name of a colleague and when I read the attributes of the row I don't find what I expect.
Following is the code I use

```
$sheet1 = 'sheet1.xml';
$getrow = file_get_contents($sheet1);
$xmlrow   = simplexml_load_string($getrow);
foreach ($xmlrow->sheetData->row as $row_0) {
    foreach ($row_0->c as $c_0) 
    {
        foreach ($c_0->v as $v) 
        {
            if ($v[0] == $preserve) /****** This changes when search for number day of the month (if $v == $day)
            {    
                $attr_0 = $c_0->attributes();
                $row = $attr_0['r'];
                break 3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the correct value in the correct row?

Comment: Can you show some data with the attributes as well, also what you expect the output to be with this data.

Comment: What I expect is to find the "index" that allows me to find the comment in a given xlsx cell. The starting data are the name of a person and the day of the month. The cross between name and day allow me to go to another xml file and find the comment. name is known but I don't know what line it is in. I find the index to find the line from sharedString.xml. The code is what you see above. So I always search for the column in the same file. the code is always the same but instead of $ preserve there is $ day (known). As my code is structured the result is not what i expect

Comment: Following is the data of a row in xml file
....
(contains the column: v= column nbr )
<row r="4" customFormat="false" ht="12.75" hidden="false" customHeight="true" outlineLevel="0" collapsed="false">
        <c r="A4" s="12"/>
        <c r="B4" s="13" t="n"><v>1</v></c>
        <c r="C4" s="13" t="n"><v>2</v></c>
        <c r="D4" s="13" t="n"><v>3</v></c>
        <c r="E4" s="13" t="n"><v>4</v></c>
        <c r="F4" s="14" t="n"><v>5</v></c>
        <c r="G4" s="13" t="n"><v>6</v></c>
        ....
</row>    
....

Comment: (this and other x rows contain the data for each day: v= pointer to another file which I dont care. I need the value in attribute of c->r)
<row r="7" customFormat="false" ht="16.55" hidden="false" customHeight="true" outlineLevel="0" collapsed="false">
        <c r="A7" s="21" t="s">
            <v>16</v>
        </c>
        <c r="B7" s="22"/>
        <c r="C7" s="22"/>
        <c r="D7" s="22" t="s">
            <v>14</v>
        </c>
        <c r="E7" s="22" t="s">
            <v>15</v></c>
        <c r="F7" s="25" t="s">
            <v>8</v>
        </c> ....
</row>
...

Comment: Sorry but dont know how to format a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. 
In the above code `$row = $attr_0['r'];` $row becomes an array $row[] and analyze it.
Thank Nigel Ren for givin me an inspiration

Answer (score 0):

Rather than scanning through the entire structure, you can use XPath to find it for you.  This code looks for a `<c>` element with a value (`<v>` element) equal to the value you are after.

As `xpath()` returns an array of matches, this means you need to use `$cell[0]`, adding on the `['r']` will then give you the attribute.

```
$getrow = file_get_contents($sheet1);
$xmlrow   = simplexml_load_string($getrow);

$cell = $xmlrow->xpath('//c[v="'.$preserve.'"]');

echo $cell[0]['r'];
```

Test file...

```
<sheetData>
    <row r="4" customFormat="false" ht="12.75" hidden="false"
        customHeight="true" outlineLevel="0" collapsed="false">
        <c r="A4" s="12" />
        <c r="B4" s="13" t="n">
            <v>1</v>
        </c>
        <c r="C4" s="13" t="n">
            <v>2</v>
        </c>
        <c r="D4" s="13" t="n">
            <v>3</v>
        </c>
        <c r="E4" s="13" t="n">
            <v>4</v>
        </c>
        <c r="F4" s="14" t="n">
            <v>5</v>
        </c>
        <c r="G4" s="13" t="n">
            <v>6</v>
        </c>
        ....
    </row>
</sheetData>
```

and using the following...

```
$preserve = 2;
```

gives me

```
C4
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesnt work. $cell returns an array(0). I tried to substitute $preserve with its numerical value but nothing. What is strange to me is that when I hover $preserve inside your code I dont get any value. Just for the record, I use netbeans to debug my scripts

Comment: Check that your data is loaded does `echo $xmlrow->asXML();` give you the original XML back.

Comment: I can see the content of $xmlrow as array but not as the original xml. Result is 0

Comment: I've added my test data and the output I get to the question, can you test this and see if that works for you.

Comment: Please don't try and add code/data as comments, add them to your question.